# How to declare CURL body for CoinBase API call in php

Tags: php, curl, coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I want use php curl to interact with coinbase api. Simple API calls that does not require data to be passed are successful. What I want to do is [create address](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#create-address).
CLI curl works. The command line curl command sample is below:

> curl https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/82de7fcd-db72-5085-8ceb-bee19303080b/addresses \
>     -X POST \
>     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
>     -H 'Authorization: Bearer abd90df5f27a7b170cd775abf89d632b350b7c1c9d53e08b340cd9832ce52c2c' \
>     -d '{"name": "New receive address"}'
>   }

My php code excerpt

```
$apiurl = "https://api.coinbase.com";
$secret = "coinbase api secret";
$method = "POST";
$requestPath = "/v2/accounts/actualAccountID/addresses";
$body = "";
$url = $apiurl.$requestPath;
$data["name"] = "curl smj6 ary";
$body=json_encode($data);

$string = $timestamp.$method.$requestPath.$body;
$sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $string, $secret);
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

if($method == "POST"){

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
}

$headers = [
    "CB-ACCESS-KEY: xxx",
    "CB-ACCESS-SIGN:$sig",
    "CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP: $timestamp",
    "CB-VERSION: 2018-03-21",
    "accept: application/json;charset=utf-8"
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// Execute
$result_json = curl_exec($ch);
```

It returns

> {"errors":[{"id":"authentication_error","message":"invalid signature"}]}

Since it works with listing user. I guess th error occurs the way iam passing post data to curl.

Similar Questions that I found on SO but none solves my issue. Please help!

1. [Invalid Signature Coinbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655711/invalid-signature-coinbase/31682238#31682238)
2. [CoinBase "invalid signature" PHP Buy API Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622045/coinbase-invalid-signature-php-buy-api-request?rq=1)
3. [How to declare CURL body for CoinBase API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42265223/how-to-declare-curl-body-for-coinbase-api-call)
4. [Api key authentication for coinbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962816/api-key-authentication-for-coinbase)

UPDATE:

```
$apiurl = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/";
$requestPath = "accounts/$accountid/addresses";
```

returns same error

Answer (score 0):

There are sites that convert the command line cURL syntax to PHP, like https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

I just pasted your command and:

```
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/82de7fcd-db72-5085-8ceb-bee19303080b/addresses");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"name\": \"New receive address\"}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer abd90df5f27a7b170cd775abf89d632b350b7c1c9d53e08b340cd9832ce52c2c";
$headers[] = "CB-ACCESS-KEY: <your api key>";
$headers[] = "CB-ACCESS-SIGN: <the user generated message signature>";
$headers[] = "CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP: <a timestamp for your request>";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: @SMJ Answer updated. Basically for each header, add a new line.

Comment: I updated my code in question. Can you please review that? If $body="" i do get an address. but then i cannot pass label to the address iam creating.

Comment: `$requestPath` is wrong. It should be the actual `account_id` like `/v2/accounts/82de7fcd-db72-5085-8ceb-bee19303080b/addresses`.

Comment: actually i pass my account id in original code. just hide that for SO

Comment: Try it like this: `$apiurl = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/";` `$requestPath = "accounts/actualAccountID/addresses";`

Comment: still same error. It works on command line as I can pass curl -data How can I do that in php ?

Comment: You're already doing it in your code `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167335/discussion-between-smj-and-icedant).